# Suppress redirection on RP-STS (ACS)

Tags: c#, wif, acs, sts-securitytokenservice

I am in process on integrating SSO on multi-tenant website. We are using ACS as RP-STS and there are multiple 3rd party IDPs in our topology.

Based on tenant configuration we change the `realm` and `homerealm` parameter in signin request for correct redirection and eliminating IDP selection page on ACS. Rule groups are set on ACS to transform input claims from corresponding IDP to correct app specific output claims. So far we have nailed down all basic requirements but one.

Some of our tenants want their website user to redirect to their IDP for login while some of them don't want redirection to IDP for login. I don't know how I can tell ACS not to redirect to IDP for login.

In my application, I am using the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property to verify LoggedIn user.

For example, if user is logged in GMAIL and we are using Google as one of our IDP. First time when user access our website in new tab of the same browser, we get `IsAuthenticated` as false in our webapp and user is redirected to ACS. But ACS finds user logged in to GMAIL and redirects user back to our website with translated claims. But if user is not logged in GMAIL, in this case ACS redirects user to Google for login. Once user logs in Google, he gets redirected to our website with translated claims.

So I still want ACS to handle heavy lifting work of token creation, parsing and claim transformation if user is logged in but in case if user is not logged simply redirect user back to website with some status.

Is this really possible? Is there any specific action (wa) I should be using instead of `wa=wsignin1.0`?

UPDATE:
If I have to stop redirection, is there anyway I can process SignInRequestMessage on RelyingParty/webapp it self? Presently I prepare SignInRequestMessage based on tenant and WriteQuerystring out to RedirectResult, which performs GET request on ACS and to Google eventually. Instead if I can POST SignInRequestMessage in application itself and parse the response? Is this possible?